# Loop pagination using a dynamic integer

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So far I can scrape the initial page and save. What I'm trying to do is use the page count on the site to determine the number of loops.

The page count is found in the code with the 'count =', which in this case is 18. How can I loop my code to scrape and save each page?

Secondly, my code scrapes each `url` 3 times.

Is there a way to not have the duplicates?

Lastly, I'm using 'strip' to get the dynamic integer for the loop. The element returns the text: Viewing page 1 of 18. Using 'strip' returns the correct number if the last number is a single integer. In this case, since there are two (18), it only returns the 8. Can't figure that one out for the life of me.

Appreciate the help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv

chrome_driver = "C:/chromedriver.exe"
Chrome_options = Options()
Chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9015")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, options=Chrome_options)
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")

### set zipcode and search length ###
zipcode = "84105"
search = "1yr"   #search option: 1mo 3mo 6mo 1yr 2yr 3yr All
url = 'https://www.redfin.com/zipcode/' + zipcode + '/filter/include=sold-' + search
https = "https://www.redfin.com"
driver.get(url)
#####################################

###  get page count  ###
count = soup.find('span', class_='pageText').get_text() #grabs total pages to grab
pages = count.strip('Viewing page 1 of') #gives a number of pages to paginate
print("This search has " + pages + " pages" + ":  " + zipcode)
print(url)
########################

data = []
for url in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/UT/")}):
    print(https + url['href'])
    data.append(https + url['href'])

with open("links.csv",'a') as csvfile:
    write = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ' ')
    write.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just noticed that you want to loop without duplicates:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        print("Extracting Page# 1")
        r = req.get(url.format("1"), headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        total = int(soup.select_one("span.pageText").text.split(" ")[-1]) + 1
        urls = [f'{url[:22]}{a.get("href")}' for a in soup.select(
            "a.slider-item")]
        for page in range(2, total):
            print(f"Extracting Page# {page}")
            r = req.get(url.format(page), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            links = [f'{url[:22]}{a.get("href")}' for a in soup.select(
                "a.slider-item")]
            urls.extend(links)
    mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(urls))
    with open("links.csv", 'w', newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["Links"])
        writer.writerows(zip(mylist))


main("https://www.redfin.com/zipcode/84105/filter/include=sold-1yr/page-{}")
```

Comment: That's so much cleaner and fast! The code says it's extracting pages but only writes 20 links. I changed "write" to "append" but it just appends the same 20 links. Since I have no idea what you just did there, I don't know how to fix it. ...added my full code above

Comment: @RyanEvans yes that's correct because there's too much duplicates. you can just remove `set` and you will found all duplicated links

Comment: This works beautifully. One question though. I'm new to coding and I'm trying to work through your code and figure out exactly how you did it. I'm using an open chrome browser with selenium so I can see the code interact with the browser. How can I adjust your code to watch it work? I've been messing with it all night and can't seem to figure it out. Thank!

Comment: @RyanEvans you can debug the code within your IDLE. which idle you are using ?

Comment: I'm doing everything within Sublime. I've added print(links) so I can see what its doing. ALso, just noticed it's grabbing page 1 results x number of pages.

Comment: @RyanEvans you should check how to debug the code using `Sublime` as am using `VSCode` on my side. please clarify the point of `it's grabbing page 1 results x number of pages.`?

Comment: I added print(links) right below urls.extend(links). It outputs "Extracting Page #" (as you originally had it) then all results are from page 1. The output only has page 1 results duplicated by page count

Comment: @RyanEvans Hmm, let me check that. hold on

Comment: @RyanEvans i figured it on. will update the code shortly.

Comment: @RyanEvans code updated and fixed the issue of duplicated url, total output is `350` , full output is [here](https://paste.centos.org/view/raw/2d315791)